# How do I link PHP file with Xcode?

Tags: php, xcode

I'm new to xcode (programming in general actually) and I'm trying to create a login page. I've created the PHP file that can query the database. Now how do I link my app to this php file?

Any tutorial links or videos would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either add A web(kit) View and load the right URL

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLfp7.png)

or send form data using NSMutableURLRequest

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://yourwebsite.com/login.php?username=user&password=123"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: request completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *connectionError) {
    if(!connectionError) {
        // Handle response
        NSString* strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
}];
[task resume];
```